# How to generate and share a file?

Tags: javascript, html, share

I want to share a csv file through the [api web share](https://web.dev/web-share/), but instead of using an uploaded file as in the tutorial demos, I want to use a generated file, similar to what is done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file).

What I'm doing is

```
navigator.share({
    files: [new Blob([data], {type: type})],
    title: 'Vacation Pictures',
    text: 'Photos from September 27 to October 14.',
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
  .catch((error) => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) object, not just a Blob:

```js
const file = new File( [ "foo bar" ], "foobar.txt", {type: "text/plain" );

if( navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare( { files: [ file ] } ) ) {
  navigator.share({
    files: [ file ],
    title: 'Dummy text file',
    text: 'Some dummy text file',
  })
  .then( () => console.log( 'Share was successful.' ) )
  .catch( (error) => console.log( 'Sharing failed', error.message ) );
}
else {
  console.log( "can't share this" );
}
```

But note that this `file` member is only in the [level-2 specs](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/level-2/), which is still just a draft (accessible under `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` in Chrome).

Comment: What is foo bar text here? What will come in this?

Comment: @kb0000 that's the file content, so this file will be a text file made of "foo bar", encoded in utf8

Comment: So, when file is already being provided as foobar.txt then do we need to copy or send text (like foo bar here)?

Comment: @kb0000 if you already have a File object, then you can omit the first line (as long the variable holding it is called `file`.)